# Tez View - "Download Data" files location

Tags: logging, hive, hdfs, apache-tez

In Ambari, inside the Tez View, there is a `Download Data` button at "Details" pane inside each query.
If someone press this button, it downloads a ~1MB zipped file called, for example, "`dag_1584136991319_12180_1.zip`".
As I can see, there are 12 json files, which contains task attempts, task parts, and, the most important for me, `hive_query_id.json`, which contains the entire query that has been run.

Does anyone know where are these file located, if Linux or HDFS and which is the default location?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that these files are stored in /ats/done/ in HDFS.

Comment: Hi, what code are you refering to? It's just a path